# Adding one icon above another icons

Tags: html

I have 3 icons like this in html and **I would like to add another icon above the Facebook icon** but it always appear next to the facebook icons **NOT** above it. I tried to change but it just won't work out as I wanted. It's basically always next to the facebook icon.

**Icons I want to add: fab-fa-images (above the facebook icon )**

Can you please help doing that ?

Thank you so much

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>by Nguyên Phùng</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> 
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2daeff28dd.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="URL" class="fb" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
  <a href="URL" class="youtube" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>
  <a href="URL" class="github" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a>
</div>
</body>
<style>
body {
  background-image: url("vn.gif");
  background-position: center;
}
button{
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgb(207, 207, 207);
}
.wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: -8px;
    left: 4px;
    padding: auto;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .youtube {
    display: flex;
    width: 60px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0px;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: transparent;
  }

  .fb {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0px;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: transparent;
  }

  .github {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0px;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color:transparent;
  }



  .fb:hover {
    transition: 0.2s;
    color: rgb(0, 122, 221);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }

  .github:hover {
    transition: 0.2s;
    color:tomato;
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }

  .youtube:hover {    
    transition: 0.2s;
    color:red;
    transform: scale(1.1)
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the wrapper just add these two extra with existing.

```
.wrapper{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}
```

You can learn more on flex here - https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp

Comment: I tested your code and it worked. BUT the spacing between each icon is pretty little so how can I make it space bigger ? Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes you can. Add margins

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: flex;` and `flex-direction: column;` in your wrapper to display items vertically.

*[Here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is a guide to flexbox*

```css
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    max-width: 4em;
}

.img {   
   font-size: 45px;
   color: black;
}

a{
  text-decoration:none
}


.img:hover{
    transition: 0.2s;
    color: green;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.fb:hover {
    color: rgb(0, 122, 221);
}

.github:hover {
    color:tomato;
}

.youtube:hover {    
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<body>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2daeff28dd.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <a href="URL" class="img image" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-image"></i></a>
    <a href="URL" class="img fb" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
    <a href="URL" class="img youtube" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>
    <a href="URL" class="img github" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answer. I did it and succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `display: inherit;` to all the `.fb` `.youtube` `.github`. This will take the value of the parent element.

You might also have to add a margin to the fb, or it might be too close to each other.

```
.fb {
    display: inherit;
    width: 50px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
```

There are more details about the CSS display property here - https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Answer (score 0):

Just have to set `display: flex` to all the icons. And create a new class for the new icon. Or `display:flex` and `direction:column` to the wrapper.